# How do I fix "lens error" on my Canon PowerShot ELPH 170 IS?

Tags: troubleshooting, point-and-shoot, error, powershot

Every time I turn on my camera, Canon PowerShot ELPH 170 IS, it says "lens error" and powers down. I have tried taking the batteries and memory card out and replacing the batteries but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2):

If the camera is telling you that you have a lens error, then you probably have a lens error. I guess just changing batteries is not enough. Did you check [the manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/1/0300017431/01/elph170is-160-cu-en.pdf)? It says:

Lens Error

- This error may occur if the lens is held while it is moving, or when the camera is used in dusty or sandy locations.
- Frequent display of this error message may indicate camera damage. In this case, contact a Canon Customer Support Help Desk.